# Creating platform independent db for mobile

Tags: android, ios, mobile

I am a iOS developer.I am developing an offline enterprise app for iOS and Android.
App is just as simple as taking a value from user and showing the corresponding value from a dictionary/map.  (Eg. put a employee id in text box and update the label with their phone number)

How do I create a platform independent dictionary/map so that both the platforms would be using the same source.
I am planning to to use a jSon instead of sqlite, since the number of entries in map are around 1000 and will never change in size.
 What approach should I follow ?

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using Apache Cordova:

http://cordova.apache.org/

If you know JavaScript, then this could be a solution.  The platform independent code would be written in JavaScript.  The only native code would then be your text box and label.

"When using the Cordova APIs, an app can be built without any native code (Java, Objective-C, etc) from the app developer. Instead, web technologies are used, and they are hosted in the app itself locally (generally not on a remote http server).

And because these JavaScript APIs are consistent across multiple device platforms and built on web standards, the app should be portable to other device platforms with minimal to no changes."